# Can I fix a corrupted jpeg file?

Tags: jpeg, data-corruption

I have some jpg files on an old hard drive, and it appears they were corrupted somehow. When I try to open them it says it's an invalid file type in Windows. I first attempted a couple of repair programs, but they both said it's not a valid jpg file. I then attempted to use Gimp which gave me the error:

Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x8b 0x80

I then checked it in terminal, and it said the file type was "data file," not an image file. I'm guessing these pictures are lost forever, but wanted to throw it out there in the event someone else has seen this and been able to fix it.

Comment: There’s a good crew of tinkering types here. Can you provide an example image/not-image file that could be played with?

Comment: I absolutely can!  Is there a way to attach a file in here?  I'm not seeing it...

Comment: There are **lots** of "JPEG repair" apps out there.

Comment: There isn't a way to attach a file. The best options would be to create a github repository or to base64 encode / uuencode and upload a text representation to something like pastebin.

Comment: I've uploaded the image here...  If anyone wants to tinker, tinker away!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pazcRnk1e5v9g8TlGuPIEA-hrUIeHeio/view?usp=sharing